# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 with Javers @JaversSpringDataAuditable

Tags: spring-data-jpa, javers

@JaversSpringDataAuditable works fine with Spring Data Repository. But when I use this

`@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "3000")})`

for pessimistic locking for a query, findByXXAndXX() and used multiple Threads to call the particular api under which this query is being called, we get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at org.javers.repository.sql.finders.CdoSnapshotFinder.lambda$getLatest$1(CdoSnapshotFinder.java:51)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.javers.repository.sql.finders.CdoSnapshotFinder.getLatest(CdoSnapshotFinder.java:46)
    at org.javers.repository.sql.JaversSqlRepository.lambda$getLatest$0(JaversSqlRepository.java:69)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1556)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.javers.repository.sql.JaversSqlRepository.getLatest(JaversSqlRepository.java:72)
    at org.javers.repository.api.JaversExtendedRepository.getLatest(JaversExtendedRepository.java:98)
    at org.javers.core.snapshot.SnapshotGraphFactory.createLatest(SnapshotGraphFactory.java:25)
    at org.javers.core.commit.CommitFactory.createCommit(CommitFactory.java:77)
    at org.javers.core.commit.CommitFactory.create(CommitFactory.java:72)
    at org.javers.core.JaversCore.commit(JaversCore.java:83)
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.commit(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:82)
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$acb40bd0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
```

How can we solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code, what you have tried, actual call stack for getting answers quickly

Comment: Any update on this?